# pass all params values from javascript to controller grails

Tags: javascript, grails, controller, parameter-passing

After checking the check box, i have to check the Entered values in the form , so i have to pass all the  params from the form to the controller, if the values  are not equal, it has to raise an alert,is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do the validation on the front-end? or back-end?

To raise an alert from the back end just simply do your comparison with the params and if there is an issue, add this :

```
flash.message = "What ever your error is"
flash.alertType = "danger"
```

and then in the GSP

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
<div class="alert<g:if test="${flash.alertType}"> alert-${flash.alertType}</g:if> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    ${flash.message}
</div>
```

Comment: It will check the values from the back end and by checking the box , it has to check the values are equal or not. I tried to call the Ajax , it does nt work.

Comment: You are making an AJAX call through javascript, after doing front end validation correct? Could post some code so I could get a better understanding of what you need.

Comment: i tried your scripts with little modification it works. thank you